# Conditional formatting for 2 conditions if exist the same with 1 condition

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have one conditional formula which works well. Now, I want to use a conditional formatting for **two conditions** (using the same cell + additional one) and I've made a formula based on online tutorials, but it does not work. This is how it looks like

```
AND($Sheet1.$I1="John Doe";$Sheet1.$C1="Done")=TRUE()
```

and in the `Cell Style` I chose my own formatting.

The formula with one parameter looks like this.

```
AND($Sheet1.$I1="John Doe")=TRUE()
```

And it is the only one that works.

Can I have two formulas like this where one check for one cell, and the other one for the same cell + additional cell? I want to apply two different formatting based on the cells values.

**EDIT**

The problem is in the fact that 2 formulas occur in **the same row**. A formula with 2 conditional parameters work, but it DOES NOT work when it's in the same row.

Comment: I don't have OO installed, but I'm sure what you want is possible.  If you have the formulas in the opposite order, i.e., one condition formula first, it might be that it doesn't ever evaluate the more restrictive one.  Excel used to be that way, don't know about OO.

Comment: The Excel version is pretty much what you've shown and should work. **=AND($I1="John Doe"; $C1="Done")**

Comment: I tried your formula (plus leading `=`) with Excel 2003 and was told I had syntax errors.  I replaced `;` with `,` and `.` with `!`. I was then told I could not reference other sheets with conditional formats.  I removed the two uses of `Sheet1.`.  The result `=AND($I1="John Doe",$C1="Done")=TRUE()` worked.

Comment: why the heck do you use `=TRUE()`?? `formula=TRUE()` will be simply evaluated to the same truth condition as `formula`

Comment: @JerryBeaucaire Please try 2 cond formatting which have one **same parameter** like in my example

Comment: @TonyDallimore Please try 2 cond formatting which have **one same parameter** like in my example

Comment: @sandalone.  I do not understand **one same parameter**.  I started with your formula and changed it until Excel stopped complaining.  I tried different values for C1 and I1 and the cell with the formula was formatted only when both were as you require.

Comment: @sandalone. I tried this in case it is what you meant.  I formatted three cells in a row with these formulae: `=$I1="John Doe"`, `=AND($I1="John Doe",$C1="Done")` and `=$C1="Done"`.  As I changed the values of C1 and I1, formatting switched on and off as expected.

Comment: @TonyDallimore The problem is in numbers of parameters. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check Control Panel > Region and Language > Formats > Additional settings... > **List separator:** option wheter it is `;` or `,` and use that symbol in your formulas...

---

**Edit:** you might need to change the order of conditional formats:

- for 2003 or older version of Excel + for 2007 when you checked the **Stop** option: make sure the most restrictive condition is first
- for 2007 with multiple conditional formats: make sure the order of all applied formats that replace each other is the way you want

Comment: separator is `;` so it's not the issue.

Comment: Please try 2 cond formatting which have **one same parameter** like in my example

Comment: @sandalone if you wanted to say you need these 2 formats to apply to the same row, just check the order and stop conditions of the conditional formats (in 2003- conditional formats stop after first match, in 2007+ the default way is to apply all applicable conditional formats and the later ones will append to the previous formats (e.g. bold font from 1 condition + blue background from 2nd condition))

Answer (score -2):

For example, it seems NOT to be allowed to have functions like this:

```
AND($I1="John Doe")=TRUE() //-> format Red

AND($I1="John Doe";$C1="Done")=TRUE() //-> format Blue
```

which apply two styles.

The proper way is this:

```
AND($I1="John Doe";NOT($C1="Done"))=TRUE()  //-> format Red

AND($I1="John Doe";$C1="Done")=TRUE()  //-> format Blue
```

Comment: When you say "not allowed" what does that mean.  Are you prevented from entering the second formula?

Comment: -1 your "proper way" will work, but the explanation is completely wrong - what are you "NOT allowed"?!? it's just your first "proper" formula will be false and the conditional formatting algorithm will evaluate the second formula (in original version the first one will be true and if it is set up to stop evaluating after successfull condition, the second formula won't ever be evaluated)

Comment: I agree with @deathApril's assessment, as per my original comment to your question.

Comment: @deathApril There must be the same number of parameters if you want to apply a style to the same row. I've tried all ways and this is the only one that works.

Comment: @sandalone it has nothing to do with number of parameters, but with evaluadion order of conditional formats...

Comment: @deathApril But in my 1st example, both expressions will be TRUE as the cell I1 is always the same string. I do not understand you?

Comment: @sandalone http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cformatting.htm - see Order of Conditions for how it worked up to Excel 2003,, in Excel 2007 the logic is completelly changed - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/manage-conditional-formatting-rule-precedence-HA010074373.aspx